# Python Re Module Error

Tags: python

```
import re
numlist=list()
fhandle = open("file.txt")
for line in fhandle:
    line=line.strip()`enter code here`
    number=re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    num=int(number[0])
    sum=sum+num;
print(sum);
```

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "re.py", line 1, in 
    import re
  File "/home/shadowixzz/Downloads/PythonCourse/re.py", line 6, in 
    number=re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: you named your script `re.py`, don't do that!

Comment: Rename your file. It can't be the same name as the module you import.